# MySQL php login

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am try to check if an activation link is valid or invalid, however I am always getting the $activated_message from my code even if the activation token or email is incorrect. What's wrong with my sql statement or functions? Thanks

```
<?php
include("mysql_functions.php");

// Check if all fields are not empty.
if (!empty($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['activation_token'])) {

    // MySQL database select query.
    $mysql_select_query = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE email='" . $_GET['email'] . "' AND activation_token='" . $_GET['activation_token'] . "' AND activated='0' LIMIT 1";

    // Execute the MySQL database select query and check if POST password matches MySQL database hashed password.
    if(mysql_execute_query($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database_name, $mysql_select_query, false)) {
        // Valid activation link.
        // MySQL database update query.
        $mysql_update_query = "UPDATE Accounts SET activated='1' WHERE email='" . $_GET['email'] . "' AND activation_token='" . $_GET['activation_token'] . "' AND activated='0' LIMIT 1";

        // Execute the MySQL database update query to activate the account and check if it is successful.
        if (mysql_execute_query($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database_name, $mysql_update_query, false)) {
        // The account was successfully activated.
            echo $activated_message;
        } else {
            echo $not_activated_message;
        }
    } else {
        // Invalid activation link.
        echo $invalid_activation_link;
    }
} else {
    echo $not_activated_message;
}

// ------------------------ FUNCTION: MYSQL QUERY EXECUTOR -----------------------

// Function for executing MySQL queries.
function mysql_execute_query($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database_name, $mysql_query, $return_mysql_query_result_boolean) {

    // Create the MySQL database connection.
    $mysql_database_connection = mysqli_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database_name);

    // Check if connected to MySQL database.
    if ($mysql_database_connection) {
        // Connected to the MySQL database.

        // Execute the MySQL query.
        if ($mysql_query_result = mysqli_query($mysql_database_connection, $mysql_query)) {
            // MySQL query has executed successfully.

            // Check if any data needs to be returned.
            if ($return_mysql_query_result_boolean) {
                // Get an associated array from the MySQL result.
                $mysql_query_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysql_query_result);
            }

            // Close the MySQL database connection.
            mysqli_close($mysql_database_connection);

            // Return the MySQL query result.
            return $mysql_query_result;

        } else {
            // MySQL query has not executed successfully.
            echo "Error: " .  mysqli_error($mysql_database_connection);
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        // Could not connect to the MySQL database.
        die("Error connecting to MySQL database: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        return false;
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: Not to mention the SQL injection hole you are having.

Comment: I thought i was using mysqli? I intend to roll my code over to prepared mysqli statements in the future.

Comment: use any one `musqi` or `mysql`. Recomm: MYSQLI

Comment: @user1406186, don't do important stuff "in the future": you might never do it, and doing it now will help in training the muscle memory.

Comment: The immediate issue at hand however is that condition you use to test of such a combination exists in the database. You rely on it to return `true` or `false` apparently, but that is not how that stuff works. I suggest you take a look into the documentation.

Comment: @arkascha OP is not mixing. The API calls are all `myqli_`. (Agreed, that his own variables and functions start with `mysql_` does not help)

Comment: The docs say that mysqli_query will return false on failure though?http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @user1406186 Failure to execute the query yes. Not when no records are found. A valid query with no result is not an SQL failure.

Comment: @BartFriederichs You are right, I do apologize. Those local function names really confused me. Retracting my comments...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the fact that `mysql_execute_query` always returns a result that resolves to `TRUE` when the given query is correct.

You should read the results of the select statement, and base your logic on that, not on the fact that the query worked or not.

That being said, there is a lot wrong with your code:

- the nested-if structure in your main code is not very readable or maintanable
- you are open to SQL injection attacks, check out [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)
- connecting to the database for each query is unnecessary

Hope I helped you a little, good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the line:

`if ($mysql_query_result = mysqli_query($mysql_database_connection, $mysql_query)) {`

As it returns always true, so you get always activation message irrespective of condition.

Answer (score 0):

Please do check your update query . you are setting "activated" field to 1 then by the end of the query again setting to zero which doesnt give you intended results.

```
 // MySQL database select query.
    $mysql_select_query = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE email='" . $_GET['email'] . "' AND activation_token='" . $_GET['activation_token'] . "' AND activated='0' LIMIT 1";

    // Execute the MySQL database select query and check if POST password matches MySQL database hashed password.
    if(mysql_execute_query($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database_name, $mysql_select_query, false)) {
        // Valid activation link.
        // MySQL database update query.
        $mysql_update_query = "UPDATE Accounts SET activated='1' WHERE email='" . $_GET['email'] . "' AND activation_token='" . $_GET['activation_token'] . "' AND activated='0' LIMIT 1";
```